# IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0 tensorflow label detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, pickle, subplot

Hey guys i am using tensorflow and wanted to pass new images and find its prediction along with the image.This is my code:

```
img = plt.figure(figsize=(32,32), tight_layout={"h_pad":4})
nc=len(set(y_ftest))
for i in range(nc):
    k = np.where(y_ftest==i)
    image = batch_x[k[0][0]]
    prediction = pred.eval(feed_dict={x:X_ftest, y:y_ftest})
    logit = sess.run(tf.argmax(logits, 1), feed_dict={x: X_ftest})
    a = img.add_subplot(nc,2,i+1)
    a.imshow(image, interpolation="None")
    a.set_title(label_dict[logit[0+i]])
    i+=1
```

this is the error i get

```
     IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
 15         for i in range(nc):
 16         k = np.where(y_ftest==i)     
---> 17         image = batch_x[k[0][0]]
```

Comment: The error message tells you what's wrong here: most likely explanation is that `k[0]` is an array with zero entries, so looking up the first entry using `k[0][0]` fails. Clearly `set(y_ftest)` is not a set of consecutive integers starting at `0`. It's also possible that it's the `batch_x[...]` lookup that's failing. I suggest separating that line of code into multiple lines so that you can pinpoint the cause.

Comment: The problem is the y_ftest is initialised to zero and that nullifies the array. I tried changing it to `k=np.where(y_ftest[i])`  but the pickled set only returns array[0] and does not get incremented. Are there ways to increment the index of a pickled dataset??